# How to separate Name list from File System in Android

Tags: android

Can we separate the List of only names from the data from file system as

```
Name    Age Sex Address
dani    21  Male    US
ron     34  Male    NY
stella  23  Female  NY
steave  43  Male    US  
[End]
```

I have tried to set the Delimiters as'\t' in above data while inserting into file.
I tried

```
try 
{
fin = openFileInput("FileSystemDatabase.dat");
isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
           if (line.equals("\rName\tAge\tSex\tAddress\n"))
                 break;
    }
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\r\n\\d\t");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
           if (line.equals("[End]"))
                   break; 
           Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
           if (m.matches()) 
           {
                   text =m.group(1);
                   tv=new TextView(this);
                   tv.setText(text);

           }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i am not getting the correct result to get correct List.Is there is any simple way to get it?
Please help me..

Comment: Could you check line.contains("\t") if not use tv.setText(line.split(" ")[0]);

Comment: not done.I have used Buffered Reader is it in correct manner please help me somebody.Is it correct?

Comment: looks using Buffered Reader is correct,  could you check commenting first loop having line.equals("\rName\tAge\tSex\tAddress\n"), i think issue in Delimiters '\t'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. You will get only the names:

```
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && (line.equals("Name\t\tAge\tSex\tAddress\n"))) {
            Log.e("String ", "" + line);
            break;
        }

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals("[End]"))
                break;
            splitString = line.split(" ");
            Log.e("Name ", "" + splitString[0]);
        }
```

Output:

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/String(3713): dani    21  Male    US

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/Name(3713): dani

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/String(3713): ron     34  Male    NY

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/Name(3713): ron

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/String(3713): stella  23  Female  NY

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/Name(3713): stella

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/String(3713): steave  43  Male    US

06-28 11:30:08.009: E/Name(3713): steave

Comment: what is `splitString` that you have used?

Comment: spiltString is just a String object.
How to print in TextView?? 
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xxx);
txt.setText(spiltString[0]);

Comment: Hello!I have problem during retrieving second list as 'AGE' ,Please help me.